# Binding Command/Attribute To Element in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

I'm trying to implement the [XLabs CameraViewModel](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/ViewModel/CameraViewModel.cs) functionality into my Xamarin Forms App. Unfortunately, the given example uses XAML to bind the views with data, but i need to do it in code behind.

The following code is used to select a picture and get it's source.

```
public class CameraViewModel : XLabs.Forms.Mvvm.ViewModel
{
    ...
    private ImageSource _imageSource;
    private Command _selectPictureCommand;

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _imageSource, value); }
    }

    public Command SelectPictureCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectPictureCommand ?? (_selectPictureCommand = new Command(
            async () => await SelectPicture(),() => true));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And these commands are bound to XAML :

```
<Button Text="Select Image" Command="{Binding SelectPictureCommand}" />
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

How can I apply the same commands in code-behind for created elements?

```
CameraViewModel ViewModel = new CameraViewModel();

var Take_Button = new Button{ };
Take_Button.SetBindings(Button.CommandProperty, //*???*//);

var Source_Image = new Image { };
Source_Image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, //*???*//);
```

I've successfully binded SelectPictureCommand by doing the following:

```
Take_Button .Command = ViewModel.SelectPictureCommand;
```

However I have my doubts about it being the correct way, and the same logic cannot be applies to ImageSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the button you have:

```
var Take_Button = new Button{ };
Take_Button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding { Path = nameof(ViewModel.SelectPictureCommand), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = ViewModel});
```

For the image you have:

```
var Source_Image = new Image { };
Source_Image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding { Path = nameof(ViewModel.ImageSource), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = ViewModel });
```

Comment: I tested this code so it should work. Try to debug if when you press the button the SelectPictureCommand gets called.

Comment: Just wanted to see if there's a command assigned to it at all. I placed the breakpoint inside where the command needs to be executed ( SelectPicture() ) and it does not get called.

Comment: Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = ViewModel - dont know how or why but adding this to new Binding { } seems to fix everything.

Comment: The answer for me wont work unless - Source = ViewModel - is added. Thanks a lot for help.